# VBA CODE RUNTIME ERROR 1004 which says object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2007.

I am trying to run below code block in VBA and I am getting runtime error 1004, object defined error.

CODE:

```
Sub Delete()

If Range("A1") = "" Then
With Sheets("Filter")
Dim ARS As Long
    For ARS = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row To 5 Step -1
        If Right(.Cells(ARS, "B").Value, 3) = "ARS" Then .Rows(ARS).ClearContents
        If Right(.Cells(ARS, "B").Value, 3) = "Ars" Then .Rows(ARS).ClearContents
        If Right(.Cells(ARS, "B").Value, 3) = "ars" Then .Rows(ARS).ClearContents
    Next
End With
End If

end Sub
```

My Aim is to remove the ARS from the table in case ARS is empty.

I have many similar blocks in the Sub Delete routine for all teams ARS, FUL, LIV etc

Please see the attached image for my data.

Thanks in Advance!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd3DZ.png)

Comment: It's `xlUp` - the letter `l` as in `lambda`, not the number `1`. You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to flag the misspelling leading to an undeclared variable.

Comment: You can use `UCase` or `LCase` to capitalize or lower-case the right 3 letters... then you only will need one `If...Then` instead of three.